# How to access permission READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE file (pdf docs)in android SDK 33

Tags: java, android, android-studio

In Android 13 version or SDK 33 How to access all files in android devices and also give permission of Allow management of all files, I have try requestLegacyExternalStorage, defaultToDeviceProtectedStorage, `requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` and  `READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE`, `WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE` permission but not working.

In android 11 and 12 is working fine but In android 13 it's not working.

```
if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(requireActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            intent.setType("application/pdf");
            startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_FILE_REQUEST);
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(requireActivity(), new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
```

Comment: Think you can use the same code as on lower sdk's. Which difference did you encounter?

Comment: same code i need for min and max SDK, now in SDK 33 it's not working (google pixel mobile)

Comment: What exactly is not working? Cpme to the point please. Show the codes you used.

Comment: requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" is only for Android 10/Q devices. And MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is not for Android 10/Q. So where are you talking about?

Comment: am trying to read PDF file from storage, using Intent; this not working  in android 33

Comment: Put all the code you tried in your post. Your talking about pdf is much to vague. We are programmers. We want to see code!

Comment: updated question with  code

Comment: It is still pretty unclear what is not working as you dont tell what happens instead. And what has ACTION_GET_CONTENT to do with it all? To use it you do not need any permission to begin with.

Comment: String[] PERMISSIONS = {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}; these permission not asking in Android 13 mobile, i think now clear

Comment: You are not reacting on my comment for ACTION_GET_CONTENT. After you have done that please post a code example that makes sense. Also you continue to talk about requestLegacyExternalStorage which does not make sense as you  know now. Please rewrite your post. Keep it simple. Only one problem please.

Answer (score 0):

**MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** permission is particularly dangerous permission. It must be provide manually. Try this:

```
    val intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION)
    intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT")
    intent.data = Uri.parse(String.format("package:%s",applicationContext.packageName))
    startActivity(intent)
```

Note: The Google Play store has a policy that restricts the use of the MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission if the app is intended to be published to the store.

Comment: in android 33 it's not working.

Comment: @Mahesh. Describe exactly what 'not working'means. Tell what happens instead.

Comment: ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(requireActivity(), new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE); permission only not asking in android 13 and Intent i'll check next

Comment: @Mahesh in your question, you said *Allow management of all files* , and you request WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission here. I don't clear this problem. What's exactly permission you want request in Android 13?

Comment: String[] PERMISSIONS = {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}; these permission not asking in Android 13 mobile

Comment: @Mahesh So you want request WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions right? Did you try clear cache or reinstall app? From Android 11, if you denied permission twice, system auto make *not ask again* and don't show permission again

Comment: IN ANDROID 11 and 12 it's working file but android 13 it's not working

Comment: My god... @Mahesh.. put all code in your post. Not in comments. Unreadable. Write a good post to begin with. Remove comments.